# Folding EitherT[Future, Throwable, A]

Tags: scala-cats

Cannot figure out most idiomatic way to kinda fold `EitherT[Future, Throwable, A]` to `Future[A]`, where left side of `Either` will be represented as failed `Future`.

Answer (score 1):

Is a simple straight-forward fold not good?

```
 foo.fold(Future.failed, Future.successful).flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fold` and throw whatever `Throwable` you find on the left side

```
val foo: EitherT[Future, Throwable, A] = ???

import cats.instances.future._

foo.fold(throw _, identity)
```